How can i make that all the chart in a radar chart.js show me in hover a list of the data?
I'm trying to make a chart where the data shows up when I put the mouse in all the area generated and not only in the nodes. The idea is that the hover shows the entire data together.
This is what I have now.
This is what I want to do.
I've been trying to modify some properties that I found in the documentation, but nothing worked.
I'll let a partial copy of my code below. If you need more information, please let me know.
const data = {
            labels: Object.keys(currentDict),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Probabilities',
                data: Object.values(currentDict),
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 54, 0.7)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
                pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
                pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
            }]
        };

const config = {
            type: 'radar',
            data: data,
            options: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 200
                },

                elements: {
                    line: {
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    },
                },
                scales: {
                    r: {
                        ticks: {
                            display: false,
                            maxTicksLimit: 5,

                        },
                        grid: {
                            color: gridColor
                        },
                        angleLines: {
                            color: gridColor
                        },
                        
                        pointLabels: {
                            color: gridColor
                        }
                    },

                },
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        mode: 'index',
                    },

                },

                
                
            },

        };

I tried to modify the tooltip and added things to options.hover but nothing work, can anyone help me please?
The data is just a list of keys and other list of values of a dictionarie.

I've find a partial answer to my question. I was able to make that the tooltip shows me all the information, but the hover shows up when i put the mouse in any part of the chart, and not only in the area formed.
Is an alternative given that the hover in the area it seems very difficult to do. Also i discovered that the Vue.js library echart can do what i want, but i'm not allowed to use vue.js.
I let my code below as a partial answer.
const data = {
        labels: Object.keys(currentDict),
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Probabilities',
            data: Object.values(currentDict),
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 54, 0.7)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 54)',
        }]
        };

        let gridColor;

        if (isDarkMode) {
        gridColor = 'white';
        } else {
        gridColor = 'black';
        }

        const config = {
        type: 'radar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            animation: {
            duration: 200
            },
            elements: {
            line: {
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
            },
            scales: {
            r: {
                ticks: {
                display: false,
                maxTicksLimit: 5,
                },
                grid: {
                color: gridColor
                },
                angleLines: {
                color: gridColor
                },
                pointLabels: {
                color: gridColor
                }
            },
            },
            plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: false, 
                callbacks: {
                label: function(context) {
                    let tooltipText = [];
                    const datasetLabel = context.dataset.label || '';

                    context.dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
                    const label = context.chart.data.labels[index];
                    tooltipText.push(`${label}: ${value}`);
                    });

                    tooltipText.unshift(`${datasetLabel}:`);

                    return tooltipText;
                }
                }
            },
            },
        },
        };

The principal improvements was put the plugins.tooltip.intersect = false, that allows the tooltip appears in any area of the chart. On the other hand, in plugins.tooltip.callbacks.label i putted a function that display the entire information of the chart in a list. I let the result below.

I have to do a little fixes like the title, but the general idea is partially done i think. If someone knows how to improve this, please let me know.
